# How to copy a file from a remote network to the local desktop

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, command-line, scp

So I used SSH to remotely login to another computer on a network. I have many files that I would like to copy over to my local desktop.

[image: A screenshot of the files I want]

I am trying to follow this [How-to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157381/in-ssh-how-do-i-mv-to-my-local-system) :

However, I think one of the problems is that I may not know what goes in place of `/home/name/dir`

I tried using `scp`

```
scp rrtigga@pc35.cs.ucdavis.edu:CPUTimer.h /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop
```

But then I got this error:

```
/Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use `Desktop/`...

Comment: I did and I don't see it

Comment: I think the Desktop above isn't the local one so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: I don't believe there is a rule against posting an image of terminal output / code, but if there isn't. There should be. In the future, please consider pasting the output in a code block.

Comment: Where did you enter the `scp` command? On your local computer (MacBook Air, as it seems) or on the remote computer? The command as you typed it must be entered on your local computer, not the remote one you are copying from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to give an absolute path to `scp` — the easiest way to deal with this is to go where you want to put things and use `scp rrtigga@pc35.cs.ucdavis.edu:CPUTimer.h .` (`.` refers to the current directory), or give a relative path like `Desktop`. You can also use `~/Desktop` to refer to the `Desktop` directory within your home directory from anywhere.

If you have lots of files to copy from one place, you may find [`rsync`](https://rsync.samba.org/documentation.html) more convenient:

```
rsync -avx rrtigga@pc35.cs.ucdavis.edu:foo .
```

That will copy the entire "foo" directory and its contents to the current directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the name of the file(s) you want to copy, there is no need to `ssh` to the remote server before using `scp` to copy the file(s).  This should do the trick:

```
scp rrtigga@pc35.cs.ucdavis.edu:~/CPUTimer.h .
```

This will copy the file `CPUTimer.h` from the home directory of `rrtigga` on `pc35.cs.ucdavis.edu` to the present working directory on the local machine.

If you would rather do the `scp` after using `ssh` to connect to `pc35.cs.ucdavis.edu` use `scp` like this:

```
scp ~/CPUTimer.h your_local_machine_IP_address:~/.
```

Substitute you local machine IP here ^^^

This will copy `CPUTimer.h` to the home directory of the user executing `scp` on the local machine.

Answer (score 3):

`sftp` is a useful alternative for transferring files and archives over SSH.

Start a connection while in your target directory and use FTP commmads to transfer files.

```
$ sftp user@host
Connected to host
sftp> cd /usr/local/src
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /usr/local/src
sftp> put file.tgz
sftp> get file.tgz
```

Comment: sftp is life saver...

Comment: @creek where the file 'file.tgz' sits initially?
when using "put file.tgz"
where it goes when using "get file.tgz" Regards

Comment: file.tgz would exist in the directory you were in when the sftp session was started.  If you want to upload /data/file.tgz then `cd /data; sftp user@host`

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks for showing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `scp -r username@xx.xx.xx.xxx:/remote/dir/path/ /local/dir/path/`.
For example,If I want to copy a file called `sample.txt` residing in home directory of remote system `z` having IP `ab.ab.ab.cde` to my local system `l` path `~/Desktop/` then the command will be `scp z@ab.ab.ab.cde:~/sample.txt ~/Desktop/`. You can suffix -r to scp to copy the directories from remote system.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this is because you have not put in the ditectory the file is in. Try:

```
scp rrtigga@pc35.cs.ucdavis.edu:~/CPUTimer.h /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop
```